# why setstate works on second button click flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am calculating pregnancy weeks .but the set state only update on second click.

```
 ElevatedButton (
            onPressed: () {
             setState(() {
               _selectDate(context);


               sDate = selectedDate;
               dueDate = sDate.add(Duration(days: DAYS_IN_PREGNANCY));
               DateTime today = DateTime.now();
               remaining = today.difference(dueDate).inDays.abs();
               daysIn = DAYS_IN_PREGNANCY - remaining;
               weekPart = daysIn % 7;
               weekValue = daysIn / 7;
               week = weekValue + "." + weekPart;            
             });
            },
            child: const Text("Choose Date"),
          ),
```

```
_selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
     final DateTime? selected = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: selectedDate,
          firstDate: DateTime(2010),
          lastDate: DateTime(2025),
     );
     setState(() {});
     selectedDate = selected!;
}
```

Comment: could you add _selectDate too?

Comment: `
  _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? selected = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2010),
      lastDate: DateTime(2025),
    );

    setState(() {});
    selectedDate = selected!;
  }
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your `_selectDate` function is `async` and you need to `await` for it and also you don't need to call setState inside `_selectDate`, so change you click to this:

```
 ElevatedButton (
        onPressed: () async{ //<--- add this
         var result = await  _selectDate(context); //<--- add this
         if(result != null){ //<--- add this
            setState(() {
               sDate = result; //<--- add this
               dueDate = sDate.add(Duration(days: DAYS_IN_PREGNANCY));
               DateTime today = DateTime.now();
               remaining = today.difference(dueDate).inDays.abs();
               daysIn = DAYS_IN_PREGNANCY - remaining;
               weekPart = daysIn % 7;
               weekValue = daysIn / 7;
               week = weekValue + "." + weekPart;
           });
         }
         

        },
        child: const Text("Choose Date"),
    ),
```

and change your _selectDate to this:

```
DateTime? _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
     final DateTime? selected = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: selectedDate,
          firstDate: DateTime(2010),
          lastDate: DateTime(2025),
     );
     
     return selected;
}
```

Comment: thnk uh .  this works

Comment: why my code weeks ouput wrong. can you help

Comment: what do you mean by `weeks ouput wrong`?

Comment: actually i want to calculate pregnancy and for that i have calculated current day of pregnancy like your pregnancy starts from 1 date and you are now in  12 day DAYin= 12. Now i want to calculate the current week if Day in = 12 so you are in week 2 . i tried to divide dayIn by 7 but result comes wrong

Comment: I actually  just remove  the selectedDate and return it by _selectDate, I can't understand way other logic don't work.

Comment: in simple just want to calculate current week of pregnant user

Comment: what is the week value now when DAYin= 12?

Comment: week value 5 when dayin = 12

Comment: not weekValue, week?

Comment: week shows null

Comment: output =>  SelectedDaate = 2022-10-2 , DueDate = 2023-07-9 ,  Remaining = 268 , DaysIn  = 12, week = null

Comment: what is DAYS_IN_PREGNANCY value?

Comment: static final int WEEKS_IN_PREGNANCY = 40;
  static final int DAYS_IN_PREGNANCY = WEEKS_IN_PREGNANCY * 7;